# get a broadcast to android app on BLE connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-jobscheduler

A question about registering BLE notification on android:
I am developing an app that once the android device detects our beacon/ble hardware, should write something to one of the writable characteristics of that hardware.
Trying to understand, on the android app side how can I register some intent to be called when a ble connection was made to the android framework.

since a broadcast receiver registered in manifest can no longer launch my app and android background services policy was changed, this can't be done. so..

I am trying to use JobScheduler which was designed to be launched based on criteria. this can launch a JobService to do the job.

When the app is in foreground or background this seems to be working.
The thing is, I need to be notified when the app is not running (Not even in background)